# Save window for Code app not displaying

Tags: display, window-management, code, window-manager, vscode

I installed eOS 5.1.7 Hera a couple days ago on my 2012 Macbook Pro and I'm having a hard time with using specific apps. The one in particular is Code, a default text editing app that comes with Hera. Whenever I try to save my work, the Save Options window does not appear. Interacting with the Code window does nothing. (This is also happening in other apps like VS Code and Files, but I think the solution would fix those as well.)

However, I did discover that if I press <Return> it will save the file to the default location. And if I press <Esc> it will respond again in the main window.

I'm concluding that the Save options window is not appearing for some reason, but present. I only have the built-in display on my laptop, and I keep to just one desktop view.

Does anyone have a solution or have encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think it saves automatically with every change:

[Elementary OS Code save behavior](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25471/elementary-os-code-save-behavior)

This answer says "Ctrl+S will allow you to save the file to a specific location if you haven't already."

Comment: The answer is true, but it does not allow me to save to a specific location for a new file. I'm assuming a 'Save As' Dialogue box is suppose to appear, but I'm not getting that box; Like it is hidden or invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Hera and now my windows are appearing. Gave it a few weeks of testing here and there to verify the repair. I did notice something my computer did with the displays:

Apparently, it sees two different displays instead of one (under Applications > System Settings > Displays). I couldn't remove the duplicate display, but I turned on Mirror Display and it displays just one. I'm going to keep this setting, but I would like to find a solution to the dual display bug on my laptop.

Has anyone see this kind of bug?